# Java http client and threads

Tags: java, testng, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm writing a quick load test for our API using testNG and java http client.  My threads seem to block more than expected so I want to make sure http client is doing what I think.  my basic pseudo code is

```
class 1
    @test method{
     some junk
     myHttpWrapper my = new myHttpWrapper()
    }

class 2   
    public myHttpWrapper{
      HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
      bunch of packaging up a post params
      HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    }
```

So I tell testNG to run my @test 5000 times in 120 threads.  I see lots of blocking threads in the java console. This is not my code but essentially the flow of what I am doing.  I expect that each thread testNG spawns for my test to also spawn a separate http client. If that's the case why all the thread blocking.

Here is a typical thread stack from a block as seen in jconsole:

```
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:149)
org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:110)
org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:264)
org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionInputBuffer.readLine(LoggingSessionInputBuffer.java:115)
org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:98)
org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:252)
org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:281)
org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:247)
org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:219)
org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:298)
org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:464)
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
ss.qa.test_files.HTTP_Methods.sendPost(HTTP_Methods.java:91)
ss.qa.test_files.apiHelper.ActivateCoupon(apiHelper.java:376)
ss.qa.test_scripts.myPerfTest.ActivateCoupon(BACPerfTest.java:85)
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that it's waiting on the network during those times.

It may help if you post your code related to TestNG.

Answer (score 0):

What operating system are you running this on? Java does a pretty good job at insulating you from the specific details and limits of your host OS, but one thing it can't do is surpass the number of allowable network connections that your OS's kernel, network driver, and network hardware will allow, when combined.

From http://www.techiecorner.com/34/how-to-adjust-your-window-xp-tcp-connection-to-boost-your-bt-download-speed/ :

> With the release of Microsoft Windows XP Service Pack 2 (SP2), it has limit the concurrent TCP connection to 10 connection per seconds [*sic*].

Comment: Its mostly running on mac's.  is there a way to monitor connections used?  Im fine if I am hitting a machine limit as long as its not a bug / problem with my code

Comment: @ducati1212 It looks like OS X is a lot more permissive about such things. It looks like there could be an issue with the built-in firewall limiting the number of connections, but I wouldn't know how to check that, or if it's possible to configure that or who to do so. I think you might ask Professor Google about this particular factor